# How much ashwagandha to relieve depression?

Tags: depression

I've read [this](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/12-proven-ashwagandha-benefits) article, where is the herb `ashwagandha` which could treat depression.

Particularly:

> In one controlled 60-day study in 64 stressed adults, those who took
>   600 mg of high-concentration ashwagandha extract per day reported a
>   79% reduction in severe depression, while the placebo group reported a
>   10% increase

When I look at the products with `ashwagandha`, how do I recognize what is close to `600 mg of high-concentration`?

There is usually written the percentage of withanolides.

So, how to choose the right daily amount for depression in the particular product with `ashwagandha`?

Comment: From the page you linked, did you read the next sentence? "However, only one of the participants in this study had a history of depression. For this reason, the relevance of the results is unclear." Reducing depression in people that don't have depression is likely meaningless.

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes, I read it, but in the citation there is a term "severe depression". There are probably other studies. See [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31046033) and youtube has videos where is mentioned ashwagandha for depression treatment as well.

Comment: The site you linked to is confused. The authors do have a scale item called "severe depression" but it's not measuring severe depression, it's a scale where scoring over a certain level can be used to detect depression. Changes on the scale below that cutoff don't necessarily mean anything at all. It would be like measuring blood pressure, seeing a drop in systolic from 120 to 118 (both normal), and then claiming you've cured high blood pressure.

Comment: @BryanKrause Here is another [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11194174) . I will edit the question tommorrow yet.

Comment: @xralf - your other study you linked in comments tested on rats, not humans.  Although the results indicate a **possible** benefit in rats, it doesn't mean there will be a benefit in humans

Comment: I can't find better study, that confirms or disconfirms if ashwagandha helps for depression. Should I delete the question and rather ask for "if it helps at all"?